# Openerp, How to allow acces to a field using domains restrictions

Tags: python, odoo

How to set restrict access to a field if a user is not in specified group? I know that i should use domain restrictions but I don't know how to generate this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to create a ir.model.access.csv in the security folder of your module and create user groups by creating user_access_groups.xml. And then in the view part of the field you can do the following to restrict the visibility of the field to a certain user group only:

```
<field name="your-field" groups="your-module.your-user-group"/
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Thanks And Regards